# What can stop ssh from re-attaching to an existing 'screen' session on a remote server?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, tty

What would stop the following command from re-attaching to an existing screen session on a remote server ?

```
ssh -t server2 "screen -dr admin"
```

Machines server1 and server2 both have screen sessions named '*admin*' running. 
On  server1, the command runs perfectly, re-attaching to the '*admin*' screen session.
But, when attempting the same on server2, the connection is closed with this message:

```
"screen" isn't allowed to be executed.
Connection to server2 closed.
```

server1's `/var/log/auth.log` on a successul re-attachment to screen session:

```
Jul 13 04:40:02 server1 sshd[3995]: Accepted publickey for dbkeys from 192.168.1.170 port 52434 ssh2: RSA a4:41:1e:62:66:33:35:5f:b0:d4:a7:cd:d9:b1:20:0d
Jul 13 04:40:02 server1 sshd[3995]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user dbkeys by (uid=0)
Jul 13 04:40:02 server1 systemd-logind[1144]: Removed session 9.
Jul 13 04:40:02 server1 systemd-logind[1144]: New session 10 of user dbkeys
```

server1 is running Linux Mint 17.3

```
server1 # uname -a
Linux server1 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
server1 # cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa \n \l
```

server2's `/var/log/auth.log` on failed re-attachment attempt to screen session:

```
Jul 13 11:40:32 server2 sshd[21144]: Accepted publickey for dbkeys from 77.225.135.132 port 52437 ssh2: RSA SHA256:uidABN1IbiI7jQx10VmpWrbCGgyTkGwJaIHiiG6crPI
Jul 13 11:40:32 server2 sshd[21144]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user dbkeys by (uid=0)
Jul 13 11:40:32 server2 systemd-logind[546]: New session 203 of user dbkeys.
Jul 13 11:40:32 server2 sshd[21183]: Received disconnect from 77.225.135.132 port 52437:11: disconnected by user
Jul 13 11:40:32 server2 sshd[21183]: Disconnected from 77.225.135.132 port 52437
Jul 13 11:40:32 server2 sshd[21144]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user dbkeys
Jul 13 11:40:32 server2 systemd-logind[546]: Removed session 203.
```

server 2 is running Ubuntu 16.04.2

```
root@server2:/var/log# uname -a
Linux audit.bitmark.io 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@server2:/var/log# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

server1's and server2's `/etc/ssh/sshd`_config files are identical

What is not allowing `screen` to be executed on server2  ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the login shell. On server 2, `sudosh` was being used as the login shell, instead of `/bin/bash`

Relevant line in `/etc/passwd`:

```
dbkeys:x:1000:1000:DBKeys,,,:/home/dbkeys:/usr/local/bin/sudosh
```

but, in `/etc/sudosh.conf`, the program `screen` has to be explicity allowed to run:

```
# Sudosh Configuration File
logdir                  = /var/log/sudosh
default shell           = /bin/bash
delimiter               = -
syslog.priority         = LOG_INFO
syslog.facility         = LOG_LOCAL2
clearenvironment        = yes

# Allow Sudosh to execute -c arguments?  If so, what?
-c arg allow = scp
-c arg allow = rsync
-c arg allow = screen
```

Adding the line `-c arg allow = screen` at the end of `sudosh.conf` solved the problem.